# replace fragment in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

this is my placeholderfragment

```
public  static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static int SectionNumber;
        public static LayoutInflater Inflater;
        public static ViewGroup Container;
        public static Bundle SavedInstanceState;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            SectionNumber = sectionNumber;
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {   }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Inflater = inflater;
            Container = container;
            SavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
            View rootView = null;

            switch (SectionNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    marketActivity = new MarketActivity(context);
                    marketActivity.loadMarkets(rootView);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "1");
            if(requestCode == 0)     {

                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)         {
                    Log.e("onActivityResult", "3");


                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                    movementActivity = new MovementActivity(context);
                    movementActivity.setUp(contents);

                    Inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movement, Container, false);
                    Log.e("onActivityResult", "2");
                    Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "
                            +format);

                    // Handle successful scan
                }
                else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                {              // Handle cancel
                    Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem that face me is onActivityResult when the `resultCode`  is `RESULT_OK` i want to replace the current fragment with  `Inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movement, Container, false);` I hope that i make my problem clear to u and im really sorry for mybad english

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a simpler way of doing this, but what you can do is override the onActivityResult method in the actual fragment you are starting the activity for result.

Implement in your activity that's hosting the fragments an interface for handling callbacks

```
public interface ActivityResultCallbacks {

        void onResultOK(int request, int result);
    }
```

In your fragment cast and store the reference to callback

```
private ActivityResultCallbacks mCallbacks;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (ActivityResultCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement ActivityResultCallbacks.");
        }
    }
```

Notify the callback in fragment's onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
     mCallbacks.onResultOK(requestCode, resultCode);
}
```

In your parent activity, on callback switch fragments

```
@Override
public void onResultOK(int request, int result){
  //check for result and requestcode
  Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.YourContainer, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype in onResultOK

Comment: place the onResultOK in the parent activity